# How to change custom post type status when non-admin updates post?

Tags: post-status

I allow users to submit posts (as a custom post type, "tribe_events") to my website.

**Is there a snippet I can add to my functions.php file that would change a post's status from "published" to "pending" when a non-admin updates a post?**

Currently I'm not allowing users to edit/update their posts since WordPress keeps them as "published." If I can change that functionality I could let them edit their posts (I could review the changes they made before re-publishing the post), which would be a much more user-friendly experience.

Any advice for this novice coder would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried searching the web for the answer to this but have come up empty thus far. I don't know much PHP so I unfortunately don't know where to start for creating this.

Comment: @birgire I have same question and I have my code what I have tried, should I edit this or post another question ?

Comment: I think it would be ok to adjust this one to avoid duplication, but you should ask a moderator e.g. on our chat, to be sure ;-) @PrafullaKumarSahu